# Angular фильтрация, контроллеры

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asp.net

Не могу разобраться с фильтрацией в angular. А именно:
Есть 2 контроллера, один отвечает за пользователей, другой за их местоположение. На клиентской части нужно сделать чтобы фильтрация была по местоположению с помощью selected(она готова). Проблема в том что я не понимаю как соединить 2 контроллера или какая может быть альтернатива.
Т.е. нужно использовать контроллер с пользователями, а фильтровать по контроллеру местоположению.
В Angular я новичок как и в JS так что не ругайте сильно.

Примеры контроллеров(неполные)

Местоположение:

```
function DepartmentCtrl(common, $modal, $q, $routeParams, $stateParams, $state, settings, departmentRepository, Department, branchRepository) {
        var vm = this;
        var getLogFn = common.logger.getLogFn;
        var log = getLogFn(departmentCtrlId);
        var logError = common.logger.getLogFn(departmentCtrlId, "error");
```

Юзеры:

```
function UserListCtrl(common, dialog, $modal, config, NgTableParams, $resource, $location, $state, branchRepository, userRepository) {
    var vm = this;
    var getLogFn = common.logger.getLogFn;
    var log = getLogFn("UserListCtrl");
    var keyCodes = config.keyCodes;
```

ро конструкцию "controller as переменная" знаю.

Или как передать функции из одного контроллера в другой путем наследования. Как то так.

Comment: Сервисы для этого существуют.

Comment: Неподелитесь какимни-нибудь?